# Flow velocity deviation on a stagnation point

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

I want to make sure the thing that triggers the vertical deviation (V-velocity) of a flow which is initially on horizontal path (U_Init != 0, V_Init = 0) then hit a vertical wall. Is it the pressure gradient and/or viscous forces from the Navier-Stokes equation? Apart the Slip/No-Slip condition, does it exist another boundary condition (which also explains the phenomena) that I should implement?

Thanks

Comment: For an inviscid fluid, it is only the pressure gradient.  For such a fluid, the only boundary condition is zero normal velocity.  For a viscous fluid, the only condition is no-slip (both normal and tangential).

Comment: But in general, no-slip condition may not compatible in certain circumstances (i.e Inertia effects much higher than Viscous ones in high speeds). So, I think that it's more conservative to assume the fluid should have zero normal velocity relatively to the solid surface instead of the no-slip.

Comment: It is both, not just one of them.